# Working with Shapefiles and CARTO

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, data, carto, convert

I'm a heavy ArcGIS user, and was wondering how one may bring shapefiles onto CARTO.

I see that CARTO does not allow one to upload .shp datasets. Is there a easy conversion anyone would recommend?

Answer (score 3):

You are able to upload shapefiles onto CARTO, however they have to be in a zip file with all related extensions.

They provide details in their documentation [here](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/datasets-and-data/#why-isnt-my-shapefile-importing)

> CARTO creates datasets from shapefiles by importing a single zipped file. If your shapefile is not importing, make sure that:
>
> You are uploading a zipped file, and not just one of the files it   contains, such as a .shp file.
>
> Your zipped file contains .shp, .dbf, .shx, and .prj files.
>
> Your file names all have the same prefix. For example  myshapefile.zip, myshapefile.shp, myshapefile.dbf, myshapefile.shx, and   myshapefile.prj.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to use in proj WGS 84 (Google it) EPSG 4326. 
Carto use it.
All of their tables include the_geom column, which is a geometry field that indexes geometries with the EPSG:4326 (WGS 1984) coordinate system. All tables also automatically generate and update the_geom_webmercator column, which references the column internally to quickly create tiles for maps.
More infos [here](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/datasets-and-data/)